# Do I need a View or a ViewController?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm building a custom view with an xib file that contains various subcontrols.  I've got some container control that needs to hold my custom view.  I'm kind of unclear on whether I need to make a View that somehow loads itself from the xib file, or a ViewController that does this.

However it's done, I'd like my custom view to be reusable, and something that appears in the toolbox in Xcode, along side buttons and textboxes and such, so I can visually design other views containing my custom view.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can put it in the objects list with the Apple provided controls -- that would have to be done with a plugin, and the new Xcode doesn't support that any more (or so I've seen somewhere on SO).

Comment: Is there any *other* way to put a custom control on the visual designer?  If not, that would mean that once you build your own UIView, you completely lose the ability to use the designer.  That seems...undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your component manages other view controllers (like UITabBarViewController does for example)? If yes, make it a subclass of view controller, if not, and it's just a control, like a switch or a fancy button, scroll wheel etc, then make it a subclass of UIView.

Comment: Been thinking about this some more, and I was wondering: how do I decide if my component should manage other view controllers, and when it should just manage subviews?  What are the circumstances when a sub-unit of functionality needs to be a view controller vs a view?